# whileTrue in a block closure Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

Can you use a whileTrue: inside a block closure? I can't get it to work so I suspect not. Or I am doing something wrong.

```
map := #([1 1 1 1 1]
    [1 0 0 0 1]
    [1 0 1 0 1]
    [1 0 0 0 1]
    [1 1 1 1 1]).

posx := 1.
posy := 1.
t4 := CompositePart new.
rot := (Core.Double.Pi / 4).
perspective := Core.OrderedCollection new.
1 to: 60 do: [:i | perspective add: (rot + (i - 30) asRAD).
            rot_i := perspective at: i.
            x := posx.
            y := posy.
            gsin := (0.2 * (rot_i sin)).
            gcos := (0.2 * (rot_i cos)).
            t2 := true.
            [t2 = true]
                    whileTrue: [
                    x := (x + gcos).
                    y := (y + gsin).
                    n := (n + 1).
                    mapCoord := map at: x rounded asInteger.
                    mapCoord := (mapCoord at: y rounded asInteger).
                    (mapCoord = 1)
                        ifTrue: [
                            h := 1/(0.2 * n).
                            t2 := false]].
            t3 := (i @ h  extent: 2 @ h ) asFiller.
            t4 add: t3].
```

I would like to get everything inside the whileTrue block to repeat if mapCoord isn't equal to 1. But it doesnt, it just chugs along to the next iteration in the "do:" block. I suspect Im doing something wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I don't have VW with me to check, but in Pharo the definition of the `map` array would not work, you have to prepend every `ByteArray` with `#`. For instance `#(#[1 1 1 1 1] #[1 0 0 0 1]...`.

Comment: Note also that `n` is not defined when it comes to compute `n := (n+1)`. Is it an ivar? Or are you in a workspace where variables are automatically defined?

Comment: Yes, a block can be within a block. Your observation that "it just chugs along to the next iteration in the "do:" block" suggests that `mapCoord = 1` more often than you expect. Given that the behavior isn't what you expect, add some debugging code. Either print to the transcript or add a halt/breakpoint.

Comment: The array seemd to work, atleat in workspace. But I changed it. Then I changed the condition (mapCoord = 1) to (mapCoord < 1). And then I got the expected behavior. I think I didn't realize that it was that condition that gave me my issues. Thank you.

Comment: I will dig into your code later on (I'm sure Leandro has a nice answer for you).  I want just comment the coding style.  Your code is hard to read as you don't use any comments and using variables like `t1, t2, t3, h, etc`.  Such variables do not help reading your code.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I see.

At every `do:` iteration, both `x` and `y` are initialized to `1` and then, inside the `whileTrue:`, to something between `0.8` and `1.2`. Thus, the first assignment of `mapCoord` evaluates to `#[1 1 1 1 1]` and the second to `1` because `#[1 1 1 1 1] at: 1` is `1`. Thus, `t2` becomes `false` and the `whileTrue:` exits.

More clearly

```
x := posx.                                             "x = 1"
y := posy.                                             "y = 1"
gsin := (0.2 * (rot_i sin)).
gcos := (0.2 * (rot_i cos)).
t2 := true.
[t2 = true]
   whileTrue: [
      x := (x + gcos).                                 "0.8 <= x <= 1.2"
      y := (y + gsin).                                 "0.8 <= y <= 1.2"
      n := (n + 1).
      mapCoord := map at: x rounded asInteger.         "mapCoord = #[1 1 1 1 1]
      mapCoord := (mapCoord at: y rounded asInteger).  "mapCoord = 1"
      (mapCoord = 1)
         ifTrue: [
            h := 1/(0.2 * n).
            t2 := false]].                             "t2 = false"
```

Answer (score 3):

Syntactically there's no reason that it shouldn't work and as you can run the code, the answer to your question is: Yes you can!
If you think the while loop doesn't do what you expect, i suggest you don't "do it", but rather try the "debug it" command. That'll allow you to step through your code statement by statement. You can inspect all variables along the way and maybe find out what's wrong.

Some remarks about your code:

- you use x/y separately but you're actually talking about a `Point`, which has a x and y property. It also supports large parts of the number's protocol, which means you can send the message `rounded` to a `Point`, too. You can create `Point` objects via `@` like: `point := 4 @ 5`. Points also allow arithmetics like `point * 4` or `point + something`.
- `rounded` returns an `Integer`, so there's no need to explicitly convert it via `asInteger`.
- you have a method `asRAD` but there's already a system method `degreesToRadians`
- you shouldn't number your variables. The decompiler does that because it doesn't know better, but if you don't know how to name your variables, at least name them after the type they have. `t4` could be `aComposite`

Answer (score 0):

```
[:i| | eye x y gsin gcos coordinate notLessThanOne h |
" So I can see it too. Yes--A while loop inside a block is fine "
eye := perspective add: (rot + (i - 30) asRAD).
X := posx.                                     " x = 1 "
y := posy.                                     " y = 1 "
gsin := (0.2 * (eye sin)).
gcos := (0.2 * (eye cos)).
coordinate := notLessThanOne.
[ coordinate < 1                              " op changed to < "
] whileFalse: 
      [x := (x + gcos).                       " 0.8 <= x <= 1.2 "
       y := (y + gsin).                       " 0.8 <= y <= 1.2 "
       n := (n + 1).                          " grows forever?  "
       coordinate := map        at: x rounded." is #[1 1 1 1 1] "
       coordinate := coordinate at: y rounded." is 1            "
      ].
h := 1/(0.2 * n).
parts add: (1@h extent: 2@h) asFiller
]
```